# How to create tcp/ip packets using java?

Tags: java, packet

**Is there any library support in java to create a packet from scratch?**

I need my project to create a packet editor, with which I can edit fields in layers 2, 3 and 4, and I want to send those packets via pc NIC. It would be nice if the program is written in Java.

Do anyone know of this kind of program?

Answer (score 3):

Yes [Jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) will not only allow you to create a packet, but gives tools to send and recieve packets as well.

Comment: i see this solution in the NET i want to use Scapy , but i dont see java wrapper to this program...

Comment: You didn't mention any of that in your question. Jpcap is very easy to use and has plenty of tutorials for creating and manipulating packets.  I would recommend it highly

Comment: @RobWagner link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

There are some Physical Memory Limits in Windows OS check it out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx